# Spring Configuration class placement best practices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use configuration classes (Java classes with the `@Configuration` annotation) to configure my beans. In general I want to avoid stereotype annotations (like `@Service` and `@Component`) and component-scanning my whole project.

Are there any best practices on where to put my Configuration classes? There are different setups that come to my mind:

- **Put configuration classes in a separate package on the root level of your module**

```
- src
 - config
  - SomeServiceConfiguration.class
 - dao
 - controller
 - service
  - SomeService.class
```

Where you register a `SomeService` bean in `SomeServiceConfiguration`. My biggest problem with this is that you lose the chance to use visibility modifiers. Every class has to be public in every package to construct the bean, this can be a real bummer in bigger projects. The upside is that I can obviously just scan the `config` package to register my beans.

- **Put configuration classes in the same package as the class you want to register**

```
- src
 - dao
 - controller
 - service
  - SomeService.class
  - SomeServiceConfiguration.class
```

This allows you to use visibility modifiers, but managing the configuration files become a hassle. Your configuration files are now littered through your whole application, you will have to put in more effort to manage them. Although I start to think that this might be the favorable approach.

Are there any methods preferred by the community? Which one is preferred for bigger projects? Which one scales the best? Please note that I don't want to use stereotype annotations.

Comment: What's the problem with component-scanning the whole application?

Comment: Slower application startup, mainly. This can be considerable for bigger projects.

Comment: True. If you care about app startup speed for auto-scaling, I'd suggest looking into `@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true)` and `@Lazy`. During development you'll save a lot of time just looking for annotations to figure out what/where different components are, over reading procedural code initializing those components. Especially true for bigger projects ;)

Comment: AFAIK the problem also arises from the fact that it is just going to go through each of your class files while looking for components/configuration classes, this won't be solved by lazy bean initialization.

Answer (score 1):

> but managing the configuration files become a hassle. Your configuration files are now littered through your whole application, you will have to put in more effort to manage them

Disagree. If you know you have to modify the definition of a specific controller bean  you know where looking --> `controller/config`

It could depend on the number of beans you have... you should avoid large class with lot of beans definitions... So depending on that It will be better to split or not...